# cant insert jsp form data into database through servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Whenever I try to add data from jsp form, then the url changes and then nothing happens. I checked web.xml file everything is ok... After I hit the submit button it goes to new blank page with the url = /servlet name. I tried inserting data manually by using the same connection and it works fine.

jsp form:

```
<form action="add_patient" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="fname" required> <br /> 
    <input type="text" id="mname"> <br /> 
    <input type="text" id="lname" required> <br />
    <input type="text" id="address" required> <br /> 
    <input type="number" id="contact" required> <br />
    <select id="gender" required>
        <option value="">Choose here</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date" id="dob" required> <br /> 
    <input type="number" id="alloted"> <br /> 
    <input type="text" id="problem" required> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Add Patient"> 
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Input">
</form>
```

Servlet file:

```
public class add_patient extends HttpServlet
{
    private Connection con=null;

    private PreparedStatement stmt=null;

    private final ResultSet rs=null;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,
        IOException,
        ParseException,
        SQLException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out=response.getWriter())
        {

            // add_patients ap = new add_patients();

            String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
            String mname=request.getParameter("mname");
            String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
            String address=request.getParameter("address");
            int contact=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contact"));
            String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
            String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
            int alloted=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("alloted"));
            String problem=request.getParameter("problem");

            out.println(address);

            try
            {
                dbconnection db=new dbconnection();
                db.getConnection();

                con=dbconnection.getConnection();
                stmt=(PreparedStatement)con.createStatement();

                String sql="INSERT INTO patient (fname,mname, lname, address, contact, gender, dob, room_no, problem)" + "            VALUES (' " + fname + " ', ' " + mname + " ', '" + lname + "', '" + address + "', '" + contact + "', '" + gender + "', '" + dob + "', '" + alloted + "', '" + problem + "' )";

                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                if (stmt.executeUpdate(sql) > 0)
                {

                    request.getSession().setAttribute("error", "sorry the operation failed!please try again.");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("add_patient.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
                else
                {
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("add_patient.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If needed.. database connection:

```
public class dbconnection
{
    private static String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/HMS";

    private static String driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    private static String username="root";

    private static String password="";

    private static Connection con;

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            try
            {
                con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                // log an exception. fro example:
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection.");
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // log an exception. for example:
            System.out.println("Driver not found.");
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the webserver error log? Also, I suggest you remove your `catch(Exception)` and let the exceptions be propagated through the `throws` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` values need to have a `name` attribute in order to be sent to the server in a POST or GET HTTP request. That should cause that all your `request.getParameter("...")` lines will return null and fail with a `NullPointerException` the first time you try to use these values.

As @LittleSanti said, you should check the SystemOut/SystemErr logs for any exception thrown and also make good use of the `catch` blocks if you intend to manage those exceptions by yourself.

Comment: Thanks mate but i already solved it ... the problem was that i missed the name tag>thanks anyway mate !! cheers.